# Qual é problema com este código que pega o maior e menor valor?

Tags: python, condição

Quero exibir a soma dos número digitados assim como o maior e o menor número digitados, somente com `while`, `if` e `else`:

```
contador = 1
maior = 0
menor = 0
S = 0  # 1º NÚMERO A SER SOMADO

while contador <= 5:
    num = int(input("Digite o " + str(contador) + "º valor:"))
    if num >= maior:
        maior = num
    if maior < num:
        menor = num
    S += num
    contador += 1
print("A soma de todos os valore é igual a", S)
print("O maior valor digitado foi", maior)
print("O menor valor digitado foi", menor)
```

O programa mostra a soma e o maior valor, mas não mostra o menor valor.

Comment: Você depurou o código? Fez um teste com números escolhidos e acompanhou o que cada linha do seu código faz? Eu diria que o principal problema do seu código pode ser dividido em duas partes: 1) você testa `maior` com `num` pra definir `menor` (deveria testar `menor`); 2) o valor de `menor` já começa muito baixo (igual a 0). A não ser que o seu input contenha números negativos, jamais vai ter um valor menor do que esse. Programar requer "experimentar" com a lógica. Se vc não fizer isso, dificilmente vai aprender corretamente.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Tem dois problemas. Você precisa inicializar o menor número com um número que seja o maior número para garantir que ele não será pego a não ser que o menor número digitado seja ele mesmo. Isso pode ser feito com [`sys.maxsize`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize). Também há dois erros na condição de verificação do menor `maior < num`: precisa comparar com o menor e não o maior, e precisa verificar se o `num` é menor que `menor`, não ao contrário.

```
import sys

contador = 1
maior = 0
menor = sys.maxsize
S = 0
while contador <= 5:
    num = int(input("Digite o " + str(contador) + "º valor:"))
    if num > maior:
        maior = num
    if num < menor:
        menor = num
    S += num
    contador += 1
print("A soma de todos os valore é igual a", S)
print("O maior valor digitado foi", maior)
print("O menor valor digitado foi", menor)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/3vPntJ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cambivvd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **Github** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/PickGreather.py).