# Como criar uma função para achar o maior valor em uma lista?

Tags: python

Não estou conseguindo inserir esse algoritmo dentro de uma função

```
max_trip = 0

for val in trip_duration_list:
    if int(val) > max_trip:
        max_trip = int(val)
```

Comment: E como tem que entrar na função? Você precisa dar critérios, o que é parametrizado, o que retorna.

Answer (score 4):

```
def maior_valor(lista):
    try:
        if len(lista) == 0:
            return None

        maior = lista[0]

        for valor in lista:
            if valor > maior:
                maior = valor

        return maior
    except TypeError:
        return lista
```

**Considerações:**

1. Devido a tipagem dinâmica do Python, não há como garantir que o parâmetro recebido pela função seja do tipo esperado. A estrutura `try/catch` é utilizada para controlar o fluxo do programa caso a entrada não seja iterável. Quando for, itera o objeto verificando seu maior valor; quando não for, retorna o próprio elemento;
2. Se o parâmetro de entrada possuir tamanho 0, será retornado `None`, pois não há valores para serem comparados;
3. O valor inicial de `maior` sempre será o primeiro elemento da lista, pois isso contorna o problema de se iniciar em 0 mas a lista de entrada possuir apenas elementos negativos. O maior valor em `[-1, -2, -3]` não pode ser 0.

**Limitações:**

1. Por comparar valor a valor, não é permitido que a lista possua valores de tipos diferentes, tal como `[1, '2', (3,)]`. Isso até faz sentido, pois não é previsto nativamente uma forma de comparar tipos distintos. Se considerar o fato de, geralmente, mas não obrigatoriamente, listas serem homogêneas, isso deixa de ser uma limitação, porém para tuplas, que costumam ser heterogêneas, continuaria com o problema.
2. O comportamento da função pode ser estranho quando a entrada é uma *string*, pois ela será iterável e será retornado o último caractere na ordem alfabética. Isto é, `maior_valor('anderson')` retornaria `'s'`;

**Utilização:**

```
assert maior_valor([1, 2, 3, 4]) == 4
assert maior_valor([-1, -2, -3]) == -1
assert maior_valor('anderson') == 's'
assert maior_valor(5) == 5
assert maior_valor([]) is None
assert maior_valor('') is None
assert maior_valor([1, '2', (3,)]) == [1, '2', (3,)]
```

**Leituras adicionais:**

- [O que significa float("NaN") e float("inf") no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/289538/5878)
- [Achar o número máximo e mínimo em lista em uma string](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/346896/5878)
- [Pegar maior número de itens em uma matriz de lista em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170186/5878)
- [converter uma lista de string em uma lista de números inteiros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/301022/5878)
- [Lógica para obter o menor valor lido do usuário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/286534/5878)
- [Uma lista para receber 20 números inteiros e armazenar em uma lista e imprimir o maior elemento da lista](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203676/5878)
- [Qual é problema com este código que pega o maior e menor valor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177468/5878)
- [Em Python, quais as consequências em usar 'is' no lugar de '=='](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38104/5878)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o próprio `max()` para fazer isso. Exemplo:

```
list_1, list_2 = [123, 'xyz', 'Rafinha', 'abc'], [325, 600, 199]
print "Max value: ", max(list_1)
print "Max value: ", max(list_2)

#Max value:  Rafinha
#Max value:  600
```

Se for uma necessidade criar um método para isso você só precisa incluir essa lógica em  um método.

Answer (score 1):

Uma das forma interessantes para resolver esta questão é utilizar uma função anônima (lambda). Neste caso, a lógica deverá ser montada de seguinte forma:

1. Importa a biblioteca **functools** juntamente com seu método **reduce**;
2. Criar uma variável para armazenar os valores de sua lista;
3. Criar uma variável para armazenar o maior valor obtido da lista;
4. Exibir o resultado.

Com esta lógica podemos implementar o seguinte código:

```
from functools import reduce

numeros = [6, 5, 7, 4, 3, 2, 9]
maior = reduce((lambda i, j: i if (i > j) else j), numeros)

print(maior)
```

Quando executamos este código o método **[reduce](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)** aplica a função de dois argumentos - função **[lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda)** - cumulativamente aos itens do iterável - **numeros** - da esquerda para a direita, de modo a reduzir o iterável a um único valor. Neste caso, o único valor será o **maior** valor da lista.

Portanto, ao executar este código recebemos como resultado o valor...

```
9
```

...que, por conseguinte, é o maior valor obtido da lista.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você precisa criar uma função e dizer que ela recebe uma lista como parâmetro:

```
def verificaMaior(trip_duration_list):
```

depois você precisa setar um valor inicial à variável que você deseja comparar:

```
max_trip = trip_duration_list[0]
```

logo apos esses dois pontos básicos você precisa percorrer sua lista verificando se existe algum numero maior que sua variável de comparação:

```
for val in trip_duration_list:
    if max_trip < val:
        max_trip = int(val)
```

Feito isso é só retornar sua variável com valor atualizado (o valor atualizado só sera setado se caso exista um numero maior em sua lista):

```
return max_trip
```

Código completo:

```
def verificaMaior(trip_duration_list):
  max_trip = trip_duration_list[0];
  for val in trip_duration_list:
    if max_trip < val :
      max_trip = int(val)
  return max_trip

print(verificaMaior([1, 2, 3, 4, 10]))
```

O print final é para mostrar no console o retorno da sua função.

Comment: E se a lista for `[-1, -2, -3]`, qual é o maior?

Comment: nesse caso retornaria o próprio max_trip  certo?
o código funcionaria certo se eu fizesse max_trip  = trip_duration_list[0] correto? 
desculpe é que estou aprendendo ainda e tento ajudar com o pouco que sei rsrs

Comment: Exato, falei disso [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/289564/5878).

Comment: Obrigado pelo feeedback :)